# How to tell if a Puppet role has been applied to a node?

Tags: puppet, roles, puppet-enterprise

I'm trying to verify whether a particular Puppet role has been applied to a set of nodes.

I'm using Puppet Enterprise.

What I would like to see is lines akin to `"INFO: applying role <role_name>"` in the node log or in the Puppet master log.
I haven't found anything like that or similar to that, neither looking at the events log on the node nor in the Puppet Master log.

Does anyone know where to find this information, or at least a way to work around this limitation if needs be?

Comment: You can view the applied classes in the log, and presumably your role(s) are in the applied classes in the catalog.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I used the Node Graph available in PE:
https://puppet.com/docs/pe/2017.2/index.html